# GTK3 tabs with big icons

Tags: python, application-development, quickly, gtk3, glade

I want to implement something similar to the ubuntu software center's tabs.

[image]

What widget is it?

Any working example in python where I could take a look?

Is this widget available in Glade?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Gtk.Toolbar, see `/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/globalpane.py` for how it is created.

Comment: Will take it a look and I'd be back

Comment: Ok it is a Gtk.Toolbar, and the tabs are buttons. Now, I know this would be out of scope for this question but, I cant find how to set the visual active state for those buttons...

Comment: The buttons are instances of a subclass of `Gtk.ToggleButton` so you can use `set_active(is_active)` where `is_active` is a bool

Comment: thanks, actually a toolbar can have many different buttons so, I added a ToggleButton. They look different though, maybe the have some styling hack there.

Comment: They have their own drawing methods, see the class `SectionSelector` in `/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/buttons.py`